# Programmatically create the following variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to restructure my data so that it fits in with another piece of code. I need to convert my data (which is a name,value pair) into the following structure so that that it is processed correctly. Using JQuery how would I do so?

```
{items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};
```

Right now I've got a `$.each` loop which is feeding each name,value pair in but I don't know how I'd get that exact structure.

Comment: What exactly is your original structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why use jQuery? Do it with javascript.

The following assumes your source is an object named `values` with properties, as opposed to an array with numeric indices:

```
var output = { items: [] };

for (key in values) {
  if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    output.items.push({ value : values[key], name: key });
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't ever use for( in ) to iterate over arrays, as it will include all properties of the array object! Use a normal for-loop instead.

Comment: @x3ro From the answer - "The following assumes your source is an object"

Comment: Please use `Object.keys` instead of `for ... in` && `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @jbabey: Yeah, it is just worth mentioning that, because it is not that obvious and I often see people doing it.

Comment: @Raynos If you intend to [support most browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), don't use `Object.keys`.

Comment: @meagar wrong. If you intend to support most browsers, use ES5-shim.

Comment: @Raynos Or, use the code that works without hacking in missing functionality. `Object.keys` sits nicely in the "Untested Shims" section of ES5-shim, which proudly states it "is not likely to behave as advertised in a large cross-section of browsers" and that "'As closely as possible to ES5' is not very close". By it's own readme/disclaimer it is not production-quality code.

Comment: @meagar meh, it's more verbose and slower. It's better to use faster features when they exist and emulate them when they don't exist.

Comment: @Raynos Please don't bring performance into it, dumping 1000+ lines of JS onto the page which get evaluated each request whether you use all its shims or not? You will not win the performance argument, which isn't worth having in the first place.

Comment: @meagar woh? ES5-shim not production quality code? A lot of people have been working on it, it's pretty solid.

Comment: @Raynos [Go. Read](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). I'm not making this stuff up. **"This package requires quite a bit more attention and testing. It is not likely to behave as advertised in a large cross-section of browsers.

"As closely as possible to ES5" is not very close. Many of these shims are intended only to allow code to be written to ES5 without causing run-time errors in older engines. In many cases, this means that these shims cause many ES5 methods to silently fail. Decide carefully whether this is what you want."**

Comment: @meagar Yes, that's correct. ES5 shim cannot emulate all of ES5, but a sensible subset it can deal with. And `Object.keys` is part of that sensible subset. Just because the ES5 shim cannot do the **impossible** does not make _not production quality code_

Comment: @Raynos This really isn't constructive. It's the authors of the software that are arguing against using it, I'm just agreeing with them. If you have a problem with this, please go talk to them.